Kafka connect message key is automatically encoded in base64
 #Connector:
 - name: some-connector #source-connector2-name
config:
  connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector #fullClassPath
  mode: timestamp
  timestamp.column.name: update_ts
  query: SELECT id, name FROM customer_account
  transforms: createKey, ExtractField
  transforms.createKey.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
  transforms.createKey.fields: id
  transforms.ExtractField.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
  transforms.ExtractField.field: id
  topic.prefix: secret.value://secret.txt
  validate.non.null: false

key field id is integer type. When message is produced to kafka, in kafka logs I see that the message key, id is base64 encoded and is string type. I want it to be displayed without being base64 encoded as a normal number.
I tried some key converters from online solutions. But none of them worked
